# Which class of text can I Use?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, text-rendering

I am doing a project with JOGL (Java OpenGL) and I have a problem. I have boxes in the canvas. I can move the canvas and I can zoom in and out. I need to put text in these boxes (Using TextRenderer) but the problem is that the text does not move and does not zoom in or out like the boxes.

I think this is a problem of TextRenderer, that cannot be moved or sized in run time.

I need help to figure out if there are other text classes to make this work?

I make the zoom like this:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Is there any ohter way to make the zoom? Is difficult to find a good tutorial (and updated) of that.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What else do you have on your screen? Changing the font size when the zoom changes would work for you? One other option is to draw the text on images and use them as textures of the boxes...

Comment: I have boxes and segment that join that boxes (is like a graph). I think to make images, but I know the text in run time.

The size is ok but the problem is that the text doesnt move like the other parts of the graph

Comment: Please post a whole example, not just 5 lines of code. Moreover, ask your JOGL specific questions on the official JogAmp forum. Why do you assume that the legacy text renderer is to blame instead of your own code?

Comment: This post shows an example in OpenGL/C++. You may check if it is applicable to JOGL - http://learnopengl.com/#!In-Practice/Text-Rendering